# Get size of an array in C++ 17 using pass by reference

Tags: c++17

Is there a way to find the size of an array, using pass by reference. The size function works well inside the main function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
int hello(int arr[]){
  cout<<arr<<endl;
  //cout<<size(arr)<<endl;
}
int main(){
  int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,6,7,2};
  hello(arr);
  cout<<arr<<endl;
  cout<<size(arr)<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing array by value so `hello` function takes as its parameter decayed type - `int*`.

When you pass array by reference, you need to pass one additional non-type template parameter which is length of array and is deduced, therefore inside `hello` you don't even use `std::size` to get array's length, just use `N`:

```
template<class T, size_t N>
int hello(T (&arr)[N])
{
  cout<< size(arr) <<endl; // 7
  cout << N << endl; // 7
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you pass an array to a function, it becomes a pointer, and there is no way to get the size from that *(it will always report 4 or 8 bytes - the size of a pointer value!)*.

If you need to process an array in a func, you will need to pass in the size as an argument to the function.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int hello(int arr[], size_t count)
{
  for(size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
  }
}
int main(){
  int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,6,7,2};

  hello(arr, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int));

  return 0;
}
```

The better alternative in C++, is to use std::vector instead. *(which will store the size as a member variable)*

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void hello(const std::vector<int>& arr)
{
  for(size_t i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i)
  {
    std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
  }
}
int main(){
  std::vector<int> arr = {1,2,3,4,6,7,2};

  hello(arr);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the benefit of having size(arr) in C++17, if it can't be called inside a function? I am well aware of the function size in vector.

Comment: "Once you pass an array to a function, it becomes a pointer" - this is true only for passing by value.