Pass array by reference and find its size
How to pass an array by reference and find its length. Currently I have the below code, this does not seem to print the actual array size. Can we use sizeof() or size() to print array size?
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int ArrayLength(int &arr){
    int l = 0, h, mid;
    h = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    
    return h;
}

int main(){
    int len, value;
    cout << "Enter the length of the array: ";
    cin >> len;
    int *arr = new int[len];
    cout << "Enter the elements of the array: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    cout << "You entered: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    value = ArrayLength(*arr);
    cout << value << endl;
}

tried to use sizeof()

Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59573618/get-size-of-an-array-in-c-17-using-pass-by-reference

int ArrayLength(int &arr , int  len){ ... h=len;  ...  or since you are using C++, why not use vector ?

Unlike other languages, the length of the array in C++ is not stored with the array.  It is stored in the memory manager of the heap.  If it is allocated using new, there is no standard way of telling the size since every tool chain has a different heap management.
Instead of dynamically sizing using new, you could use std::vector.  If you did, then the size is the .size() member.
